# pjp.getArgs() is only capturing 1 argument

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I am using ProceedingJoinPoint in my springboot application to capture arguments passed to `log.info`. I am using aspectjweaver-1.9.7. I have added the following dependencies in my maven pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version> 
        </dependency>
```

I have created a library which is basically a wrapper around slf4j logger. So whenever `log.info` or `log.debug` is called, I have written an `@Aspect` class called *LoggerAspect* , in which I have a `@Around` Method which will do the required work.

Here is the @Around Method

```
@Around("call(* org.slf4j.Logger.info(..))")
    public void injectLogConfigInfo(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(pjp.getArgs().length);
        Object[] args = logMod(pjp.getArgs());
        pjp.proceed(args);
        MDC.clear();
    }
```

Now, when i am implementing the logger in my application , i am facing the following issue:

Example: `log.info("This is test of info", SomeObject);`

when i am passing this, **pjp** is only picking up the first *String* but it is ignoring the object. I had read that it returns all the arguments as an `object[] array`. The method `logmod(pjp.getArgs())` does some processing on the object array which **pjp** returns. I am not that proficient in posting questions so do forgive me for missing out on details. 

Due to restrictions at my org,  i cannot post the whole code but i have included the required bits. Now I know that when debugging, it is beneficial to view the whole picture but I do not have that priviledge. So even if you do not have the exact answer, if you can share your experience whether you have faced this issue and what you did to resolve it?

 Thanks

Comment: I bet the problem is in the code you are hiding from the community here, i.e. in the `logMod` method. Unless proven otherwise, this is my working hypothesis. In my experience, `getArgs` does exactly what you expect it to do. If you disagree, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just snippets.

Comment: But the logMod method is being called after pjp.getArgs() and that is why i used a print statement to check. I do understand your point though about not providing enough information. I will try to add more information to give everyone a better picture.

Comment: Was anything unclear about the term MCVE? Follow the link and read, please. I want code, not text. I cannot debug prose. As a developer, you should know better than to ask like this. And don't come up with lame excuses like being unable to share code. I don't need company secrets, only a reproducible example. Besides, how confidential can a method transforming an array be anyway?

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution, @kriegaex you were correct , the problem was with my aop.xml file in which the weaver configs were present. I had added include statement in `<aspects><aspects/>` block, which was supposed to be added in `<weaver></weaver>` block. Also the expression inside the include statement was wrong as well. there was a fault where I had messed up the position of `*` inside my **include** and somehow when I corrected these errors, everything started working.

This was my old aop.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name = "com.org.saas.observability.LoggerAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

and this is the new aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>

    <aspects>
        <!-- Aspects -->
        <aspect name="com.org.saas.observability.aspect.LoggerAspect"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-Xlint:ignore">
        <include within="com.org..*"/>
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

I am new to this so all the changes i have done is by trial and error, i did not go in depth as to why these changes were required due to limited time.
also, this link helped in changing the include expression as it was similar to my problem: [NoSuchMethodError with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413186/nosuchmethoderror-with-aspectj)

@kriegaex I apologize for not uploading an MCVE , I got too busy with another task and I should have put in more effort. Will remember to always add an MCVE  with my future questions.

Comment: This explanation is certainly **not** an answer to your original question. You were claiming that the aspect worked, but `pjp` was only picking up the first argument in a list of multiple arguments. Changing _aop.xml_ would neither cause nor repair that behaviour, it is completely unrelated. I am still convinced that there was a bug in your `logMod` method, causing it to return an incomplete array of arguments or something similar. Maybe you had an _aop.xml_ problem, too, but the root cause of the problem described in your original question definitely was something else.